# Displaying all posts of a category in full view on one page using their single.php template

Tags: templates

I would like to display all posts of a certain category in full view on one page, but would like to render them in the same look and feel as they were rendered using the single.php template. How ist this done?

Answer (score 0):

May be this image will be helpful
[image]

Comment: Your answer is helpful regarding summary and fulltext, but the style is not derived from the single.php template.